# How can I pass a fail test in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a little problem with Selenium IDE. When I open an website and it fails because of timeout, Selenium won't run the next tests where I created a while loop so it will always refresh the webpage if it's not loaded.
My question is, how can make Selenium pass on the next command if the "open" command fails for timeout. Or please suggest any other workaround in case the page is loading continuously .

Thanks, Alex

Comment: How can do you create loop in selenium IDE?  If open fails how your page display?

Comment: I use while command and endWhile from the Flow control plugin and also attached an extension document to the IDE.
My command fails because the website loads continuously and fails after 30 sec of timeout, but my problem is after the "open" command fails because of the timeout, the IDE doesn't enter the next commands where I wrote the while loop, after the fail the tests stops completely.